# Pulling the GPS coordinates from google maps app's "red pin" into another app (android & iOS phones)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

Apologies up front - I'm not overly technical but helping a developer partner find an answer to a problem. Feel free to be as technical as you like in response though. I'll get him to look at the answers!

We're trying to pull the location (GPS coords) of the red pin dropped in the google maps app when you do a search (on iOS or android), to use in a separate app.

The key to this is that it pulls the info you've already searched for in google maps, NOT having to search again within the second app. i.e. using google maps API in the second app is off the table.

Options so far seem to be...

1) Run an intent to request the data in the background. However, it seems that the intent has to push coordinates to the gmaps app, and can't just "ask" the coordinates of the current pin.

2) Use the google maps API to allow the user of the second app to login to their account so it can pull the account Maps history (i.e. can see the most recent place in the search history). However, it seems that the google maps API doesn't give access to this data.

3)....??

We're stumped. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to get the coordinate data? It'll depend on your use case (when and how "red pins" are created), but you can circumvent using maps with it.

Comment: Thanks Andy, we're looking into that now. Happy christmas!